String Conversion in ADF IF Condition in Azure Data Factory
Hi I am getting out put from set activity (integer variable) and I am using the same in if condition activity. However I am getting below error, can please help how to resolve this.
expression I am using @greater(int(activity('Lookup1').output),0) and
error I am getting "The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type"
Appreciate for help.

What value is coming from Lookup activity?

@activity('Lookup1').output will result in array of Json data only. In order to get the correct value from the lookup activity output, you will need to give the proper value in the expression. To write the proper expression, follow the below approach.

I have taken a sample dataset in lookup activity. When pipeline is run, the output of lookup activity looks like this.

{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 3
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime ...",
    .............
}

To get the value of id, the expression should be given like @activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].id.

The overall expression to be given in if condition activity is

@greater(int(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].id),0)
In this expression replace id with the correct key value.


Thank you for your inputs. it is working well.
